# How to string assembly without changing the original string?

Tags: c

Strings can only return pointers. I don't want to change the value of the string. I just want to use an unchanging string as the basis, and then add other different strings to the back.

Input:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str1[100]="begin";
    char str2[100]="str2";
    char str3[100]="str3";
    char str1_copy[100];
    strcat(str1,":");
    strcat(str1,str2);
    puts(str1);
    strcat(str1,str3);
    puts(str1);

}
```

Output:

begin:str2 begin:str2str3

Expected:

begin:str2 begin:str3

Comment: If you don't want to change `str1` you should not concatenate to it. Either use a temp variable to hold the combined string or use `printf("%s:%s\n", str1, str2);` or print each part separately.

Comment: After appending `str2` to `str1`, why do you expect `str1` to _not_ have `str2` appended when you append `str3`? Why do you have `str1_copy[]`? `puts( str1 );`. You **do** expect the original string to be changed...

Comment: You already have an array to hold the copy. Why don't you use it?

Comment: Do you have to use `puts`?

Comment: You can't change a string withouth changing the string.  That should be self-evident?  So if you want to preserve a string while constructing a string that is the same with something appended, you'll need to create a new string for the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have appended something to `str1`, then you have changed `str1`.

So either you need to start with a fresh copy in each case:

```
    strcpy(str1_copy, str1);  // First assembly
    strcat(str1_copy,":");
    strcat(str1_copy,str2);
    puts(str1_copy);
    strcpy(str1_copy, str1);  // New assembly
    strcat(str1_copy,str3);
    puts(str1_copy);
```

Or you can "reset" `str1` by re-establishing the terminating 0 before each new assembly:

```
    size_t str1_len = strlen(str1);  // Remember the original size of str1

    strcat(str1,":");
    strcat(str1,str2);
    puts(str1);

    str1[str1_len] = 0;  // Reset str1 before next assembly
    strcat(str1,str3);
    puts(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `puts`? If you do then you can't achieve what you wish without using a temporary string variable and `strcat` as it automatically places a newline character on the end of any string that it passes to the standard output.

You could use `printf` as follows:

```
char str1[100]="begin";
char str2[100]="str2";
char str3[100]="str3";

printf("%s:",str1);
printf("%s ",str2);
printf("%s:",str1);
printf("%s ",str3);
```

or if you were looking to output to a stream, say a file:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");

fputs(str1, fp);
fputs(":", fp);
fputs(str2, fp);
fputs(" ", fp);
fputs(str1, fp);
fputs(":", fp);
fputs(str3, fp);
fputs("\n", fp);

fclose(fp);
```

You could place the functionality into a function:

```
#define NUM 2
void Print(char* string);
int main()
{

    char strings[NUM][100]={"str2","str3"};

    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        Print(strings[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Print(char* string)
{
    char str1[100]="begin";
    printf("%s:%s ", str1,string);
}
```